Error -2147217887 connecting to SQL Server Express using MSOLEDBSQL in Excel VBA
I'm trying to connect to a new SQL Server Express database (SQL Server 16.0.1000) and I can establish the connection with a .BAT file and also SSMS, but not in VBA. The name in SQL Server Management Studio is:
Data Source=James-desktop\SQLEXPRESS.History

I have used each of the connectionStr values shown below and they all produce the same error (the connection string output is different for all, but the rest of the error msg is unchanged).
connectionStr = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=James-desktop\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=History;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
connectionStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=James-desktop\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=History;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
connectionStr = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=James-desktop\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=History;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
connectionStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=(LocalDb)\v16.0;Initial Catalog=History;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
connectionStr = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=James-desktop\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & _
    dbFilePath & ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

Error:

Attempting to establish connection to the database... Connection
String: Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data
Source=James-desktop\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=History;Integrated
Security=True;Connect Timeout=30 Error Number: -2147217887 Error
Description: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check
each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done. Failed to
establish connection to the database. Connection failed!

Here's the VBA, and again, I tried all of those connectionStr values separately.:
Sub TestDatabaseConnection()
    Dim dbFilePath As String
    Dim connectionStr As String
    Dim conn As Object
    
    ' Set the database file path and connection string
    dbFilePath = "C:\Beaker\Market Data\Database\History.mdf"

    connectionStr = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=James-desktop\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & _
        dbFilePath & ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
    
    ' Print the connection string to the immediate window for debugging
    Debug.Print "Attempting to establish connection to the database..."
    Debug.Print "Connection String: " & connectionStr
    
    ' Open the connection
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    On Error Resume Next ' Continue execution even if an error occurs
    conn.Open connectionStr
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' Print the error details to the immediate window
        Debug.Print "Error Number: " & Err.Number
        Debug.Print "Error Description: " & Err.Description
        Debug.Print "Failed to establish connection to the database."
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling to default behavior
    
    ' Check if the connection was successful
    If conn.State = 1 Then
        Debug.Print "Connection successful!"
        ' Close the connection
        conn.Close
    Else
        Debug.Print "Connection failed!"
    End If
    
    ' Cleanup
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub

Here is the BAT file I can use and it connects fine:
set server=James-desktop\SQLEXPRESS
set database=History

rem Test connection using sqlcmd with Windows Authentication
sqlcmd -S %server% -d %database% -E -Q "SELECT 1" 

rem Check errorlevel to determine success
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo Connection successful!
) else (
    echo Connection failed!
)

I do have Integrated Security (Windows Authentication) setup, and since it works with the BAT, that presumably can't be the problem, nor firewall limitations, etc.
I would really appreciate some guidance.

Try changing Integrated Security=True by  Trusted_Connection=Yes, as show here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/attach-a-database-file-on-connect-to-a-local-sql-server-express-instance/

Fantastic, that worked in this string:     connectionStr = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=James-desktop\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=History;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Connect Timeout=30"

I’m voting to close this question because the person asking this question did not do proper research on how to build a connection string to a Microsoft SQL Database
